# JS Fetch bypass http/s Requirement

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, server

I have an expressJS server that has the below program flow. I want to make it so that index.js can fetch from my api. Issue being that fetch can't work outside of HTTP/S (err:  URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.) and I'm using localhost:PORT/

My question is. Can I create some sort of workaround to allow me to perform a fetch request on my own api. Either that or find a way to serve my own results from my internal script to my webpage's script. Many thanks.

## Program Flow

App.js(ExpressJS) **=>** async run Puppeteer.js **=>** serve index.html **=>** results returned from puppeteer.js **=>** api populated **=>** index.js **SHOULD** be able to pull from api

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by localhost:PORT, exactly? What's the *protocol*?

Comment: I use app.listen(port, () => puppet.puppet()) where port is a number (i.e 8080)

Comment: I have just run req.protocol and it claims http, would I need to prepend that onto my fetch parameter in index.js? i.e fetch(http://localhost:8080/api) ?

Comment: Well what happens if you try that?

Comment: Apologies for asking something I could've tried, was a little flustered. I've tried but attempting a fetch from (http://localhost:8080/api) yields the same error. Luckily my end user has advised I can use a different solution but I would still like to know how to solve this for future reference

Thanks

Comment: You can by pass by calling functions internally and using `next()` in express framework.